# React - map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm setting the values ​​in this state inside useEffect, but for some reason after some updates it starts to give an error, map() is not a function.
I tried to pass a TimeOut, tried to put a ternary in the render but it still persists in the error.
It's as if in the same second that it's going to update it tries to render, will anyone be able to identify where I'm going wrong?

**useEffect:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (vehicle.status === 200) {
      setTotalCount(vehicle.count);
      setVehicles(vehicle.vehicles);
    }
  }, [vehicle.status, vehicle.vehicles]);
```

**Render:**

```
 {vehicles?.map((vehicle) => (
                <CardExplore
                  bodyVehicle={vehicle}
                  isFavorites={false}
                  termLease={termLease}
                  termFinance={termFinance}
                  key={vehicle.VIN}
                  valueDown={rangeValue}
                  valueMpy={mileage}
                  leaseToFinance={leaseToFinanceState}
                  loading={loading}
                />
              ))}
```

[Error happening even the Results being an array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X26Ym.png)

Results is the array I'm setting in the state, you can see that it's an array and it has items inside it, but still.

[Array Results being set in state.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybltG.png)

Comment: you should use `return` statement in the `map` function

Comment: I think we'd need to see more code to understand what's going wrong. If `vehicles` is indeed an array, `vehicles.map` should work, but probably it's only becoming an array later... For example, can you show the declaration of `vehicles`?

Comment: I agree, more code would be helpful

Comment: Same error, with return

Comment: @HasanAbbasi [`return` isn't needed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax) in this case.

Comment: What code do you need? The matrix result?

Comment: `setVehicles(vehicle.vehicles);` did you mean `vehicle.results`?

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Vehicle is the return of my Redux, inside it I set the Results in Vehicles

Answer (score 1):

Append this `vehicles &&` conditional check before your map to prevent this error when the array is undefined.

```
{vehicles && vehicles.map((vehicle) => (
                <CardExplore
                  bodyVehicle={vehicle}
                  isFavorites={false}
                  termLease={termLease}
                  termFinance={termFinance}
                  key={vehicle.VIN}
                  valueDown={rangeValue}
                  valueMpy={mileage}
                  leaseToFinance={leaseToFinanceState}
                  loading={loading}
                />
              ))}
```

Comment: Alternatively use `{vehicles?.map?.(` if you want to use [optional chaining syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_function_calls).

Comment: @GustaMello show your `useState` decalration. Based on that it can be `vehicles.length>0`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath   const [vehicles, setVehicles] = useState<any[]>([]);

Comment: `useState<any[]>([])` should not cause the error what you are receiving. your api may be returning `undefined` or `null` sometime and that might be causing this issue. You can log `vehicle.vehicles` to check